# group by multidimensional array based on 2 values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, group-by

I'm wandering if any of you can help me pls.

I'm having an array of values in each row (`Order,Material,StorageBin,Batch,Greasing(yes,no),Qty`)...800 rows

I'm done with groupBy function...it returns all the values with total QTY...

Problem is I need to groupBY components for greasing so I was thinking to add a GROUP NUMBER...Component1 can be with Component3,4,5 as GROUP1 then Component2 can be with Component6,7,8 AS GROUP2...

one COMPONENT has many ORDER NUMBERS but also can connect more COMPONENTS for greasing...

basically:(`if greasing = yes check if component is in group...if no create group and add component...but all that based on ORDER NUMBER so I can tell why do they connect`)

it does my headache...any one please?!

DATA

FROM:

```
[4363348,comp1,C01020001,1,130,greasing],
[4363348,comp2,C02060201,1,130,greasing],
[4363348,comp3,C01040001,1,130,No],
[4363349,comp1,C01020001,1,130,greasing],
[4363349,comp4,C02060201,1,130,greasing],
[4363349,comp5,C01040001,1,130,No],
[4363350,comp6,C01020001,1,130,greasing],
[4363350,comp7,C02060201,1,130,greasing],
[4363350,comp5,C01040001,1,130,No]
```

TO:

```
[4363348,comp1,C01020001,1,130,greasing,1],
[4363348,comp2,C02060201,1,130,greasing,1],
[4363348,comp3,C01040001,1,130,No,0],
[4363349,comp1,C01020001,1,130,greasing,1],
[4363349,comp4,C02060201,1,130,greasing,1],
[4363349,comp5,C01040001,1,130,No,0],
[4363350,comp6,C01020001,1,130,greasing,2],
[4363350,comp7,C02060201,1,130,greasing,2],
[4363350,comp5,C01040001,1,130,No,0]
```

Comment: do you have a small set of data and the wanted result from it? please add what you have tried, too.

Comment: the explanation does my headache.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the *Material* column and get the muber from the string and take an integer third value and add one.

```js
const getMaterialNumber = s => 1 + Math.floor(s.match(/\d+$/) / 3);

var array = [[4363348, 'comp1', 'C01020001', 1, 130, 'greasing'], [4363348, 'comp2', 'C02060201', 1, 130, 'greasing'], [4363348, 'comp3', 'C01040001', 1, 130, 'No'], [4363349, 'comp1', 'C01020001', 1, 130, 'greasing'], [4363349, 'comp4', 'C02060201', 1, 130, 'greasing'], [4363349, 'comp5', 'C01040001', 1, 130, 'No'], [4363350, 'comp6', 'C01020001', 1, 130, 'greasing'], [4363350, 'comp7', 'C02060201', 1, 130, 'greasing'], [4363350, 'comp5', 'C01040001', 1, 130, 'No']],
    result = array.map(a => [...a, a[5] === 'greasing' ? getMaterialNumber(a[1]) : 0]);

result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```